# Localization resources not changing on certain hyperlink controls in a page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, localization, cultureinfo

[image]

Above is the screenshot of the site in development...

We have a DropdownList control and on its SelectedIndexChanged it postbacks, and we then change the site culture and it then loads the respective resources files.

**DropDownList ASP.NET Code**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" runat="server" CssClass="select-language" AutoPostBack="true">
       <asp:ListItem Value="en-US" Text="English" title="/images/Flag_USA.gif"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="it-IT" Text="Italiano" title="/images/Flag_Italian.gif"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="fr-FR" Text="Française" title="/images/Flag_French.gif"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Common class inherited by all of the web pages**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

public class languagebase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        try
        {
            string LanguageCode = Request["ctl00$ucMenu$ddlLanguage"]; // Language Drop Down Control in Front End
            if (!LanguageCode.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                setCulture(LanguageCode);  // Set Culture language from drop down
                Request.Cookies["LanguageCode"].Value = LanguageCode; // Update REQUEST Cookie language from drop down
                SetCookies(LanguageCode); // Set Cookie language from drop down
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            setCulture("en-US"); // Set default language 
            Request.Cookies["LanguageCode"].Value = "en-US"; // Update REQUEST Cookie language to default
            SetCookies("en-US"); // Set default language 
        }
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }

    private static void setCulture(string LanguageValue)
    {
       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(LanguageValue);
       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageValue);
    }

    public void SetCookies(string strLanguage)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["LanguageCode"].Value = strLanguage;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["LanguageCode"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
    }
}
```

**Extension Method (just for sake of info)**

```
public static Boolean IsNullOrEmpty(this String original)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(original);
}
```

**Example Control on which Localized Resource is not loading**

```
<li>
     <img src="/images/my-listing.png" alt="" align="absmiddle" /><asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkMyProperties" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="hlnkMyProperties"></asp:HyperLink>
</li>
```

**Problem at hand**

> > Here, if I reload the page from the browser's addressbar then resources are loaded correctly.
> >     I am just imaging how it is possible that the certain controls have English resources and some have old Italian resources when switching the culture?

I hope I have explained it well.

Comment: this happens only if you  reload the page from Browser's AddressBar or every time page reloads ?

Comment: @Thomas problem occurs when language is changed from dropdownlist and when I reload the page i.e `F5` or Ctrl+F5 it loads the pages correctly !

Comment: this may be happening because of browser's cache. To check it load your page then clear browser's cache then hit`F5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the HyperLink control to the following syntax and voila! It's working now.

```
<li>
    <img src="/images/my-listing.png" alt="" align="absmiddle" /><a ID="hlnkMyProperties" runat="server"><%= GetLocalResourceObject("hlnkMyProperties")%></a>
</li>
```