# 2 postbacks required to change language in multilanguage website using imagebutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual

I have successfully implemented a multi-language website in which user can change language by clicking one of the imagebuttons.
I used a Hiddenfield to store code of language that was selected by the user (on Imagebutton click event).
My InitializeCulture method looks like this:

```
     protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
    string culture = "Auto";
    string selectedValue = Request.Form["ctl00$HiddenFieldLang"];
    switch (selectedValue)
    {
        case "1": culture = "Auto";
            break;
        case "2": culture = "zh-HK";
            break;
        default: break;
    }

    if (culture != "Auto")
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
        //ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

This works fine. But it takes 2 postbacks to change the language of the page. I'm guessing, in one postback (which changes nothing), the hiddenfield's value is set. In second postback, actual translation takes place.

How do I implement it so that the page is translated in just one click of imagebutton?

Thanks!!

Comment: Change your ImageButton to a regular button to see if it still takes 2 clicks.  I seem to remember there being some issues with ImageButtons and postbacks in certain scenarios.  If a regular button clears up your issue, look into using a regular button and setting the background of it to your image.

Comment: As I understand it, Khushboo's using the Form collection so it shouldn't really matter what control is used as the control's aren't initialized when InitCulture is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the replies.
I managed to solve this problem with the help of [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1705865/4534820.aspx/1?Re+2+postbacks+required+to+change+language+in+multilanguage+website+using+imagebutton) link.

But I have another issue now. 
I have a masterpage and I put the Hiddenfield and the Javascript function to set the value of hiddenfield in my masterpage. In the URL of all my pages, I have a querystring with the language id. So, whenever the language changes, I want to change the querystring as well.

Is there any way I can fetch the URL of current content page from the masterpage and do a Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer from SetHiddenValue(val) function itself and ensure that the text is translated?

Comment: You may change window.location just in javascript with a new language parameter and handle this parameter in the InitializeCulture method. This way you don't need an additional hidden field for selected language.

Comment: By language parameter, do you mean using the querystring value in InitializeCulture? I have already tried that, but apparently InitializeCulture() method does not recognize querystring, perhaps because it runs very early in the lifecycle of a webpage. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Try once again. The Request.QueryString must be accessible at any period of page's life cycle.

Comment: wow. Thanks a lot. It is working now. I had tried accessing Querystring value in InitializeCulture earlier and it did not work. I tried again and it works. Thanks a lot for prompting me to try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You may add client-side handler for imagebutton's click event and set value on the HiddenFieldLang on it. 
Or you can get an control that caused a postback in InitializeCulture method and if it one of buttons used for switching a language then apply appropriate culture.

The first option in my opinion is preferred as you don't need check which control cause postback each time.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the Multi-Language site in ASP.NET and had some issue once... you can find the required code in the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081189/localization-resources-not-changing-on-certain-hyperlink-controls-in-page) with an problem's solution regarding Hyperlink in the answer by me itself. And here I think you have to find the Image control and not the HiddenField control